# Xcode export multiple archives

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I'm currently working on an iOS app that I'm distributing Ad Hoc and I wanted to know if there was any way to Archive the project multiple times / create a copy when it's built, my idea is to save one build folder as an archive and one in a path that will be accessible on the server so I don't have to copy the archive every time I have a new build, eg:

Archive A) `C:/Users/Documents/iOSProject/BuildNumberXXXX`

Archive B) `/ServerAddress/live/[manifest & ipa files]`

Comment: Question is not clear, besides `C:/Users/Documents...` - are you building it on WIndows???
Maybe what you need to look at is multiple targets... but again, question is unclear, so not sure.

Comment: Sorry I just defaulted to Windows pathing in my head, I’m building on a Mac but the question remains the same, is it possible to export two copies of an archive to two separate locations